# CEF in MFC application compile error C2061, Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, chromium-embedded

I installed and compiled CEF in Visual studio 2022 using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45439643/5518907)
Everything passed without errors. But when I add `#include "include/cef_browser.h"` to my APP, I receive compiler error:

```
1>CCardDlg.cpp
1>E:\cef3\include\base\cef_ref_counted.h(487,32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'in_place_t'
1>(compiling source file '/CCardDlg.cpp')
1>E:\cef3\include\base\cef_ref_counted.h(487,32):
1>the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
1>  E:\cef3\include\base\cef_ref_counted.h(495,2):
1>  see reference to class template instantiation 'base::RefCountedData<T>' being compiled
1>Done building project "XUpm13.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Please, help me with this.

Comment: I have the sneaking suspicion that we aren't seeing the full error message. Please show the full error diagnostic.

Comment: You have misconfigured your project, that must be tuned for C++17.